# Using the split function to group a dataframe by factor, alternatives for large dataframes

Tags: r, split

I have a question regarding using the `split` function to group data by `factor`.

I have a data frame of two columns snps and gene. Snps is a factor, `gene` is a character vector. I want to group genes by the snp factor so I can see a list of genes mapping to each snp.  Some snps may map to more than one gene, for example rs10000226 maps to gene 345274 and gene 5783, and genes occur multiple times.

To do this I used the split function to make a list of genes each snp maps to.

```
snps<-c("rs10000185", "rs1000022", "rs10000226", "rs10000226")

gene<-c("5783", "171425", "345274", "5783")

df<-data.frame(snps, gene)  # snps is a factor

df$gene<-as.character(df$gene)

splitted=split(df, df$gene, drop=T) # group by gene

snpnames=unique(df$snps)

df.2<-lapply(splitted, function(x) { x["snps"] <- NULL; x })   # remove  the snp column

names(df.2)=snpnames    # rename the list elements by snp

df.2 = sapply(df.2, function(x) list(as.character(x$gene)))

save(df.2, file="df.2.rda")
```

However this is not effective for my full dataframe (probably due to its size - 363422 rows, 281370 unique snps, 20888 unique genes) and R crashes whilst trying to load df.2.rda` later on.

Any suggestions for alternative ways to do this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use "data.table" and just key by the "snps" column. Then you can easily inspect different values.

Comment: Your `split` does not "make a list of genes each snp maps to." It does the opposite: groups by gene (the second argument to `split`).

Comment: What do you plan to do with it after the split? What's the output you *really* need?

Comment: You may need to give us a reproducible sample of the data. `factor` variables are messy and we can't tell which column is which class.

Comment: Hi all, sorry I am new to stack exchange and I realise my explanation was less than ideal. Have edited the orginal question with a reproducible code example. Thanks again!

Comment: Your final result is the same as `split(df$gene,df$snp)`. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I am looking for, thank you. I am just reading the data.table vignettes, which seem very useful, but my problem is that I need to work out how to adapt the next part of my script so that it works with data.table and not a list. I am still don't understand why I can't read in my final splitted object since as you mentioned my data set isn't that big really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a shorter way to create your `df.2`:

```
genes_by_snp <- split(df$gene,df$snp)
```

You can look at the genes for a given snp with `genes_by_snp[["rs10000226"]]`.

---

Your data set does not sound so big to me, but you could avoid creating the list above by storing your original data differently. Expanding on @AnandoMahto's comment, here's how to use the `data.table` package:

```
require(data.table)

setDT(df)
setkey(df,snps)
```

You can look at the genes for a given snp with `df[J("rs10000226")]`.

Comment: Storing in a `data.table` has other advantages as well, which you can learn about from the vignettes: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started